# How to integrate with Windows Phone's Office's/Pictures Share window?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, ms-office

Windows phone 8 applications enables to share information over some platforms, such as Email and Tap+Send (Consider this [image](https://skydrive.live.com/redir?resid=E76D2B26AFC9FD1F!658&authkey=!AMU-cFCaYGsjAZI&v=3&ithint=photo,.png)).

Can I compose a program that will be launchable from that *Share* window?
And if so, what Capability should I define in the WMAppManifest?

(Oh, and same goes for the WP8's Office Share Window)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regarding the "Photo Share" option, I found [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj662932%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) article in MSDN.
I still haven't found anything to allow the same functionality via Office.